# phpunit 5.6.4 doesn't work in php 5.6 for doctrine's dependency via composer

Tags: php, cakephp, doctrine, phpunit

I have a problem composer install dependencies.
We use php which is version 5.6.24.
When installing phpunit 5.6.4, we install doctrine needs php^7. This is our partial composer.lock after require and install phpunit.

```
"packages-dev": [
    {
        "name": "doctrine/instantiator",
        "version": "1.1.0",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/doctrine/instantiator.git",
            "reference": "185b8868aa9bf7159f5f953ed5afb2d7fcdc3bda"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/doctrine/instantiator/zipball/185b8868aa9bf7159f5f953ed5afb2d7fcdc3bda",
            "reference": "185b8868aa9bf7159f5f953ed5afb2d7fcdc3bda",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.1"
        },
```

Why does it cause and How do we fix this dependency from php 7 to 5? 
As I thought, It is possible of using phpunit 5.6.4 in php 5 as https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit#5.6.4 show. (We use cakephp 2.10.3 depending on sebastian/exporter 1.2. So we can use only under 5.6.4 phpunit version.)

and we use docker ,so we install library following command .

```
docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/app composer:1.4.1 require --dev phpunit/phpunit:"5.6.4" --ignore-platform-reqs --update-with-dependencies
```

Comment: delete the `composer.lock` and the `vendor` folder then try running `composer install` again

Comment: @delboy1978uk Thanks for your comment, but no changes .Actually, We run phpunit partially but test sometimes fail emitting error 
Fatal Error Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in [/vendors/doctrine/instantiator/src/Doctrine/Instantiator/Instantiator.php, line 95] ,or may warnings.

Comment: Make sure that you don't have php7 available on the machine running composer.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Perhaps yes, because we use docker image composer:1.4.1  from official repogitory uses php version 5.6.24.
And I notice doctrine/instantiator is not included dependencies of phpunit 5.6.4 https://packagist.org/packages/phpunit/phpunit#5.6.4 and, remove it then all my test suite passes. I don't know why it is installed despite of the fact.So, I want to know how to unable installing not dependency's packages . Anyone here could help?

Comment: @tkowt, wh not simply add your own requirement definition for `doctrine/instantiator` to your composer.json?

Comment: @TonyChiboucas Sorry, I made you to misunderstand  context  for my poor English. doctrine/instantiator is not included in phpunit 5.6.4 's dependencies. So , it should not be needed to work phpunit. Actually it works without doctrine/instantiator, and even emit Exception with it. So I don't want to install it.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas This problem is caused by [incompatible  of doctrine version](see http://www.doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html) and phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock and as they show. I can override invalid versions to use command `composer require --dev package:$correct_version` ( Of course , as well as docker environment)`, I've not known it. Thank you for your help If you write the answer, I give you best answer.

Comment: @tkowt, you found the answer. You can and _should_ answer your own question and mark it accepted. There's even a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) for it. I'll vote it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by incompatible of doctrine version [(see http://doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html)](http://doctrine-project.org/2017/07/25/php-7.1-requirement-and-composer.html) and phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock and as it show. I can override invalid versions to use command composer

```
require (or --dev) package:$correct_version
```

Of course , as well as docker environment.

Composer file can have ambiguous dependencies' match setting like ＾、〜 operator, therefore dependencies will be broken if library installed to be required by dependencies change requirements which has updated incompatible before. So we need implicitly definitions of their correct version in composer.json. Thanks to @TonyChiboucas's comment `add your own requirement definition`. It becomes a clue to resolve my problem.